# How to have the link that wraps a div also have a border radius?

Tags: html, css

```css
.circle {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a class="wrapper" href="https://google.com">
  <div class="circle">
    asdf
  </div>
</a>
```

The above code has a circle div that is wrapped by an `a` tag. The problem is that clicking on the corners of the div outside the border-radius also trigger the link click. This does not happen when the link tag is removed, but I need the link tag there. Is there any way to have the `a` tag also match the border radius such that only clicks within the circle's bounds are handled?

**Additional clarification:** The anchor tag must wrap the div. The reason for this is that the div has a click handler attached to it that stops propagation to the link above. The link is only reserved for actions such as middle mouse click, open in new tab, etc.

Comment: display:inline-block to a or display:table

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ah, perfect! Yeah, the solution seems to be to move the margin from the circle to the wrapper and then give the wrapper `border-radius: 50%`, `margin`, and `display: inline-block`. Good call!